# Change private string when button pressed

Tags: java, class, variables, printing, private

all and thanks in advance for replies.
Probably this is a elementary question but I just started learning java.
I want to print the string "username" (which changes after a button is clicked) in another class. Here's the code:

```
public class Login extends javax.swing.JFrame{

    private String username;

    private void buttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
        username = textField.getText();
    }

    public String getUsername(){
        return username;
    }
}
```

This is the class where I want to print the string...

```
public class test{
    Login login = new Login();
    String user = login.getUsername();
    System.out.println(user);
}
```

The problem is that it prints "null". 
Instead, if I put

```
private String username = "bla bla bla";
```

removing

```
private void buttonActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt){
    username = textField.getText();
}
```

it prints "bla bla bla".
What can I do?

Comment: Is that your entire source code?

The first thing that I noticed is that you have an extra } at the end of your buttonActionPerformed.

Comment: When and How is the code in Test class invoked? You cannot have simply code in the class. It must be in a method. Also based on code snippet you have provided, it is difficult to tell whteher you are attempting to print the value of username before buttonActionPerformed or after it? Can you do `System.out.println(username)` in the `buttonActionPerformed()` after you set value of username? Does it print correct value there?

Answer (score 0):

> it prints "bla bla bla"

Well you directly assigned value in username

```
private String username = "bla bla bla";
```

well, in Your case you cant access userName From other class because, you are assigning String value inside the `private` Method.

So how about assigning String value outside private method, creating a function

```
userName=textField.getText().toString();
```

In this way you can access your value